# Writing weird character in pipe when executing a command in it

Tags: c, shell, pipe, piping

So my title might not make sense, but here's my problem:

I'm writing a shell and I have to deal the pipe of course. They work, the multi piping is good, there is no overflow, but there is one problem, when I execute a command in the writing extremity of the pipe, it always writes weird character in it that I can only see when I read it with "cat -e".

Here's the command line I type:

```
$> ls | cat -e
```

Here's the output:

```
^[[?12l^[[?25h42sh$
42sh.dSYM$
Makefile$
auteur$
include$
libft$
src$
```

And here's the output without the option -e:

```
42sh$
42sh.dSYM$
Makefile$
auteur$
include$
libft$
src$
```

Anyone has any idea where that could come from?

Thanks

EDIT: here's the function where I pipe:

```
static void     launch_process(t_shell *sh, t_job *job)
{
    t_process   *process;
    int         iofile[2];
    int         pipefd[2];
    int         i;

    process = job->process;
    iofile[0] = 0;
    i = get_num_process(job->process);
    while (job->process)
    {
        if (job->process->next)
        {
            pipe(pipefd);
            iofile[1] = pipefd[1];
        }
        else
            iofile[1] = 1;
        exec_process(sh, job, iofile);
        iofile[0] = pipefd[0];
        job->process = job->process->next;
    }
    job->process = process;
    wait_for_job(job, i);
}
```

So basically, I have my list of process, which are in this case ls and cat, that I execute on after an other.

Comment: These are terminal control characters. Do you know what `-e` option does? Why are you using it at all?

Comment: I'm writing my shell with c. ^^ And yes, I know what cat -e does, the problem doesn't from the command cat -e but when I'm writing in the pipe.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. I misread this post.

Comment: I rolled back the change.

Comment: Maybe your shell has nothing to do with it. Have you tried to run these commands in a standard shell?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it doesn't do that. And tried with the shells of my friends and it doesn't do that to their shell either. I tried on zsh, sh, bash, csh. I'm just writing special character in the pipe at the beginning and I don't know why.

Comment: Probably you will have to show your code

Comment: I edited my post, tell me if you need more explanations.

Comment: `ls` is hazardous: it has numerous options that could throw off your behavior; if you had environment variables enabling `--color-always` or similar. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and use `printf '%s\n' * | cat -e` instead of `ls | cat -e` to have more reliable results.

Comment: BTW, the "shell" tag here is generally for questions about POSIX sh and shells derivative of same. Knowledge of such shells -- even their implementation -- is of no use or import to this question; thus, you might consider tagging more restrictively.

Comment: (I'd suggest using `strace` or `sysdig` to trace execution and look at exactly which process is writing the content you don't want; if it happens before the `execv`-family call that switches the active process over to your own code to `ls`, for instance, then that would put it squarely on your head; whereas if it's written by `ls`, then that provides a place to focus).

Comment: I know It comes from ls. I redirected the output on a file, exited my shell and did a cat -e, on zsh, of the file and the result is the same (weird character popping). But I think you must close to the truth about ls and the colors. It musts print the colors of the binary (because 42sh is the binary of my shell) in the pipe. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: This is printed by ls, or by your shell, or by some other code being executed by the shell (like a prompt command). There is no other possibility. The code means "make cursor visibility normal". ls normally shouldn't print it, unless it is set up in some way I'm not familiar with, so you should debug your shell. If it plays with ncurses or terminfo, look at code which is doing that.

Comment: Oh n.m you might have resolved my problem. I use termcaps and I hide the cursor and create my own cursor because reasons.

Comment: This also probably means you are not doing redirects correctly. The pipe should see what ls is writing, not what your shell is writing. Don't do redirect-fork-exec-redirectback, do fork-redirect-exec.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, n.m you were right the problem came from the termcaps and the cursor. I fixed it, and it's all good and beautiful !